# sox: How To Trim Audio From a .mp4

Tags: audio, sox

using sox how do I remove 0:20-0:25 of a .mp4 file.  So far I have

```
sox filename filename2 trim 20-25
```

Comment: and what happened?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think sox can do it, it's a tool for working with raw (PCM) audio mainly. Use `ffmpeg` for that: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking

Comment: SoX could indeed manage mp4 files BUT… only optionally and thanks to the ffmpeg library… So, at the end of the day, you are correct : D'better use ffmpeg directly.